# La « carte de boxe » : origine, applications aux autres sports, emplois équivalents ailleurs en francophonie ?

Tags: vocabulaire, québec, origine-ou-raison, anglicismes, sport

La [*carte de boxe*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22carte%20de%20boxe%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab), au Québec ; c'est probablement le [*programme*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/card/568574), probablement un anglicisme sur le modèle [*boxing card, fight card*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=boxing%20card%2Cfight%20card&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cboxing%20card%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfight%20card%3B%2Cc0) (mais seulement utilisé avec la *boxe* semble-t-il et non avec le [combat [style] libre](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26539368)/MMA), et non du sens usuel de [*carte*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/carte) en français.

---

- Depuis quand parle-t-on d'une *carte de boxe* au Québec ; est-ce bien un anglicisme ; emploie-t-on *carte de* avec d'autres sports (de combat) ; et avec le *combat libre* (MMA) qu'emploie-t-on ?
- Ailleurs dans la francophonie, de manière usuelle, hormis *programme*,
  y a-t-il un autre terme employé dans un contexte de phrase de type «
  Quel(le) [substantif] de boxe [adjectif] ce fut ! » etc. ? Est-ce qu'on
  emploierait « [affiche](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41160256#41160256) », peut-on en expliquer le [sens](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/affiche/1445?q=affiche#1441) exact, dire si on le préfère à programme, et pourquoi, puis brièvement en relater l'origine, et donner un ou des exemples (célèbres)
  d'emplois avec les nuances qui s'imposent selon le type de sport le cas échéant ?

Comment: On parlait justement de ça [dans le chat récemment](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41163174#41163174) ! On ne parlerait d'« affiche » qu'avant le match ou en référence à l'importance du match.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Oui, c'est en partie inspiré de votre discussion, j'ai même inclus ce lien dans la question ! N'hésitez pas à répondre, uniquement sur le deuxième point au besoin. Merci !

Answer (score 1):

Oui, je pense que votre "probablement un anglicisme" est probablement/possiblement juste (mais "depuis quand parle-t-on d'une carte de boxe au Québec," j'en sais rien).

Comme d'autre anglicismes possibles (et similaires), il y a aussi (surtout au Québec? ... j'en sais rien non plus) l'emploie de "**carte** de danse/bal" au lieu de "**carnet** de bal/danse" pour dire ce que "dance card" veut dire en anglais,
et puis au lieu de "**programme** des courses [de chevaux]," j'ai trouvé "**carte** de[s] course[s]" dans [cette article](https://margine.pro/alldata-captures-d-cran/) (la provenance de son auteur m'est inconnue) sur le modèle ["race-card"](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/racecard) en anglais.

Mais j'ai quand même rencontré aussi plusieurs exemples de "**carte**[s] des matchs [de catch]" sur [le site **français** du "WWE,"](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1TSNO_enUS495US520&biw=1366&bih=637&ei=lagdWqiYC-qZjwSMm4r4Aw&q=%22carte+des+matchs%22+wwe&oq=%22carte+des+matchs%22+wwe&gs_l=psy-ab.3...41980.43562.0.43974.4.4.0.0.0.0.784.784.6-1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.1.783...0i203k1j0i22i30k1.0.flWMArRrWlQ) qui me semblent pertinents à votre question, donc anglicisme peut-être bien, mais pas forcement limité au Québec (en ce qui concerne le catch, en tout cas).

(Notez s'il vous plaît, qu'il y a aussi pas mal des exemples, dans les sites français,  de "carte des matchs" en parlant de football, mais je prends ces exemples plutôt pour dire "calendrier des matchs" pour une saison entière,  et pas, comme je le prends dans les exemples "catchs," pour dire les matchs d'une seule soirée (ou, au maximum, d'un tournoi/événement d'une courte durée).

(Tiens, en ecrivant "d'une seule soirée", ça m'a fait penser que peut-être "**soirée** de boxe" pourrait servir dans la phrase: « Quelle [grande **soirée**](https://www.ladepeche.fr/article/2017/11/03/2677484-la-grande-soiree-de-boxe-ce-soir.html) de boxe ce fut ! »)

---

En essayant de trouver une connexion française (bien indirecte, je sais) avec ce sens "affiche/programme" de "carte", j'ai tombé sur le mot "carton" dans le *TFLi*, qui remarque:

> On rencontre ds la docum. le composé **carton-affiche**, subst. masc.
>   Annonce publicitaire sur carton ou papier fort (cf. G. Roy, Bonheur
>   d'occasion, 1945, p. 38).

et puis juste après cette remarque, que "carton" peut dire:

> Petit rectangle de carton, de papier fort; **carte**

et puis aussi:

> **Carte** de visite; **carte** d'invitation.

(Tout ça vaut pas grande chose comme connexion, mais je l'ai trouvée assez intéressante pour la citer.)

Comment: Merci ! Analyse bien intéressante, _soirée de boxe_ oui on dirait ça je pense bien, probablement plus avec _belle_ qu'avec _grande_ mais quand même ! À une autre époque on avait Édouard Carpentier avec les galas de lutte en français quand c'était f plutôt que e, et il avait un excellent vocabulaire technique, vu qu'il était lutteur lui-même, et il faisait de la pseudo-traduction simultanée, on riait bien !

Comment: I couldn't find equivalent French uses, but in Eng. "ticket" can be used in this sense,eg "[on the ticket tonight](https://books.google.com/books?id=0A8cAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT156&lpg=PT156&dq=%22on+the+ticket+tonight%22&source=bl&ots=hFi4OFpAeu&sig=_QCNMWwjzBxiy972Nt5y_xakN04&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq7-e3iurXAhWFRt8KHcLWAoIQ6AEIUDAH#v=onepage&q=%22on%20the%20ticket%20tonight%22&f=false)." I imagine this relates to the political notion of (a) candidate(s) "being on the ticket." Telling my age, but my 1st "raslin" hero was [Haystacks Calhoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haystacks_Calhoun)! @onvousaouï

Comment: Re: _ticket_, seems [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/ticket/618374) doesn't really know what to do with it, but there's reference to a set of principles in one example, yet the example that fits better the context you mention is _this play's the hottest ticket in town_ and they expand that to _le spectacle dont tout le monde parle en ce moment_. I also thought the VP in the U.S. is the POTUS' ticket before they're both elected, along the lines you describe. Don't know that wrestler but saw he faced Mr. Fuji, which was a ringside manager when I was watching. Thanks!